# Erase vertical white space between 2 blocks

Tags: css

I have two panel, panel1 is float left with fix width, and panel2 will take the remain width. In the panel2, I have multiple boxes which also have 2 small session, session 1 is float left, and another take the remain width. The problem that I have is the vertical white space between the first box and second box as shown in the snippet. I detect that the length of panel causes this problem. How can I fix this problem by erase the white space between the first box and second box?

```css
.prefix-clear:after {
 display: table;
 content: "";
 clear: both;
}

.box-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.box-2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: green;
}


.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;  
}


.box-2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="prefix-clear">
<div class="box-1">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
<div class="box-2">
  
  <div class="box prefix-clear">
    <div class="left">box</div>
    <div class="right">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box prefix-clear">
    <div class="left">box</div>
    <div class="right">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box prefix-clear">
    <div class="left">box</div>
    <div class="right">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want the result to look like.

Comment: I want the position of box 2 will be right below of box 1 (like box 3 and box2). Sorry for unclear request.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/babLfd8x/?

Comment: It's not quiet the solution that I want because If I want to have another div below the panel, I need to clear out the float by keeping my prefix-clear. And beside that, I would like to have the two panel vertical align top also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to remove the white-space, try `display: table-column;` for your `prefix-clear:after` declaration. More than that and we may need a mock-up to see what you are trying to achieve.